# Can we label kubernetes endpoints without labeling services?

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to label the k8s endpoints directly, without labeling the service.
The label used to be applied but after some time it used to take the service labels again, and my label was gone. Is this endpoint natural behavior? Can't we just label endpoints bypassing service labeling?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The only way to decouple `Endpoints` creation from `Service` is to create a [`Service` without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) type, would it satisfy your needs ?

Comment: In my case, I have to create a service and associate an endpoint with it, but I want to check if I can label the endpoints separately without affecting service labels. Does that make sense?

Comment: To be honest, I don't get completely your point. What's the reason behind labelling `Endpoints` object separately ? Could you share your `Service` and `Endpoints` yamls ? Or at least their fragments ? Does your `Service` have a `selector` ? When you create a standard `Service` (not the one **without selector** mentioned above) the respective `Endpoints` object gets created automatically and it has the same labels as the `Service` itself. I'm just trying to understand the reason for applying different set of labels just for `Endpoints`. Could you elaborate a bit more on that ?